# QOpenGLWidget swapBuffers happening without redrawing the scene

Tags: qt5, qopenglwidget

I am porting code from `QGLWidget` to `QOpenGLWidget` and I encounter a different behavior: using `QOpenGLWidget` some `swapBuffers()` occur in some window events (like Enter or Leave events), but `paintGL()` is not called, which ends up showing the wrong buffer.
To demonstrate I use a `QMainWindow` with a menu (opening or even hovering the menu triggers the events), and a very simple example, here in python/PyQt (but it's the same in C++). I use PyQt5 in order to compare to `QGLWidget` but the behavior is the same in Qt6.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5 import Qt
from OpenGL.GL import *


class GLW(Qt.QOpenGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        print('initializeGL')
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timer = Qt.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.prepare_sel)

    def paintGL(self):
        print('paintGL')
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timer.stop()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        print('resizeGL')
        glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)

    def buffers_swapped(self):
        print('buffers_swapped')

    def prepare_sel(self):
        print('prepare_sel')
        self.makeCurrent()
        glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)


class GLW2(Qt.QGLWidget):

    def initializeGL(self):
        print('initializeGL (2)')
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timer = Qt.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.prepare_sel)

    def paintGL(self):
        print('paintGL (2)')
        glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.timer.stop()
        self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def resizeGL(self, w, h):
        print('resizeGL (2)')
        glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)

    def buffers_swapped(self):
        print('buffers_swapped (2)')

    def prepare_sel(self):
        print('prepare_sel (2)')
        self.makeCurrent()
        glClearColor(0, 1, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1)


app = Qt.QApplication([])

w = Qt.QMainWindow()
glw = GLW()
w.setCentralWidget(glw)
glw.frameSwapped.connect(glw.buffers_swapped)
qa = Qt.QAction('Quit')
m = Qt.QMenu('File')
m.addAction(qa)
w.menuBar().addMenu(m)
qa.triggered.connect(w.close)

w.show()

w2 = Qt.QMainWindow()
glw2 = GLW2()
w2.setCentralWidget(glw2)
#glw2.frameSwapped.connect(glw2.buffers_swapped)
qa2 = Qt.QAction('Quit')
m2 = Qt.QMenu('File')
m2.addAction(qa2)
w2.menuBar().addMenu(m2)
qa2.triggered.connect(w2.close)
w2.show()

app.exec()
```

`w` uses the `QOpenGLWidget` implementation whereas `w2` is the same, using legacy `QGLWidget`. The widget normally just displays a red background in `paintGL()`, *but* also triggers a timer to prepare another buffer (let's say for future mouse selection, whatever), which is done 500ms later in `prepare_sel()`. Here the buffer is cyan, but is not displayed, and is not intended to be visible at any time.
In `w2` (`QGLWidget`) things are as expected, the window is always red.
in `w` (`QOpenGLWidget`) the window is red, at first, but when I open the menu, or just move the mouse over it, then the window becomes cyan: `swapBuffers()` has been called here (as confirmed by the print in the debug callback `buffers_swapped()`, but `paintGL()` has not, thus a new buffer has not been prepared before being displayed.
In comparison, in `w2`, the redrawing is not called when I move the mouse over the menu, but when I actually open or close it, the scene is completely refreshed, `paintGL()` is called. It is not in `w`.

Is this behavior *normal* ?
How can I prevent this: is there a way to avoid the additional `swapBuffers()` which does not occur using `QGLWidget` ? Or is there a way to force a `paintGL()` *before* it ?
Or is this way of doing things really wrong ? I mean, the "selection" buffer (cyan here) is perhaps not done the way it should, how could I do the same another way (do I need to use an additional framebuffer for this) ? But even then, the `swapBuffers()` occuring without `paintGL()` will at some point, when in a moving scene, display a buffer "from the past" and show a rendering which is not up-to-date, right ?

I just want to ensure I can call `paintGL()` before any `swapBuffers()` happens.

Comment: What's the purpose of `GLW::prepare_sel`?  You're drawing to the underlying `OpenGL` context outside of the `paintGL` call -- that's almost always a bad idea.  Does getting rid of `prepare_sel` change the behaviour?  Similarly, you probably shouldn't be drawing into the context in `resizeGL` either.

Comment: The idea was to prepare in advance a selection buffer in order to read it when the user clicks. It can be done at another moment (user click), but necessarily outside of a paint event. Here it's just used to fill the double buffer with "something else" and show that there are swapBuffers() calls which make visible a buffer that has not been prepared yet. If I remove this, but use a moving 3D scene, I guess this swapBuffers will also display the previous frame ? Or is there something in OpenGLWidget which automatically copies the front buffer into the back buffer after paintGL() ?

Comment: The resizeGL() code was just to check that things drawn here are actually not displayed - that's OK, we never see a green background - I haven't described this in my first post, sorry, and thus it is unneeded code for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, using separate framebuffers for selection or other off-screen renderings (probably using more memory resources but I had no choice). The problem was actually that:

1. `QOpenGLWidget` uses a framebuffer, and not a double buffering as `QGLWidget` was doing. Thus swapBuffers() is not actually a swap but a copy to visible screen, and
2. the widget assumes that the framebuffer is never modified until a new paint event is issued, and copies it to visible screen when it needs, without redrawing - this second point was the key actually. This is not documented at any place, so I could not guess...

So we cannot avoid creating a second framebuffer for selection in order to leave the widget's one untouched. When doing so, everything looks as expected.